# Can I ALT-TAB out of DOOM without the game auto-pausing?

Tags: doom-2016

Can I ALT-TAB out of DOOM without the game auto-pausing? Really annoying when I want to skip cutscenes I've seen already 100 times.

Comment: Windowed mode does not work?

Comment: No it does not.